# Problem with software-properties-gtk

Tags: 16.04, python

After some update I got this error when I try to start software-properties-gtk:

```
~ /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk                    
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gdk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 54, in <module>
    from UbuntuDrivers import detect
ImportError: No module named 'UbuntuDrivers'
```

What package do I need? I try to find UbuntuDrivers without success

Answer (score 0):

try those 2 answer
It seems that you mistakenly deleted the Python library package of the core Ubuntu driver. Try to reinstall the ubuntu-drivers-common package
https://t.codebug.vip/questions-1621597.htm

and

https://ubuntu.buildwebhost.com/tw/q/88605